# Invalid column name after PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I would like something like this:

```
42 | 41 | 31 |  32 | Name
----------------------------    
 O                    42  
     X                41  
                P     32  
     Y                41  
     Z                41
```

The column headers that are pivoted are also the value in the name column. The various columns can have different statuses. This is what I have but I keep getting an error saying the `ValveGroupName` column is invalid.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = stuff((select ',' + quotename(ValveGroupName)
                        from dbo.adm_ValveGroup vgroup,
                             dbo.adm_Station station
                       where station.StationID = vgroup.StationID
                         and station.StationName in ('CBRN') 
                       order by vgroup.ValveGroupName desc
                         for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')

set @query = 'select ValveGroupName,' + @cols + ' from
              (
                select vlog.status,
                       vgroup.ValveGroupName                   
                  from dbo.adm_Station station,
                       dbo.adm_ValveGroup vgroup,
                       dbo.valvegroup_log vlog
                 where station.StationID = vgroup.StationID
                   and vgroup.ValveGroupID = vlog.ValveGroupID
                   and station.StationName in (''CBRN'')
                   and vlog.logdate between ''2012-10-01'' and ''2012-10-30''
              ) x
              pivot
              (
                 max(status)
                 for ValveGroupName in (' + @cols + ')
              ) p '

execute (@query)
```

What's wrong with this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `ValveGroupName` is becoming the new column names from the PIVOT, you normally won't include that in the final select list. Since you are basically "removing" the `ValveGroupName` to become the new columns, SQL Server doesn't have that column any longer so it throws an error.

The code would normally be:

```
set @query = 'select ' + @cols + ' 
          from
          (
            select vlog.status,
                   vgroup.ValveGroupName                   
              from dbo.adm_Station station
              inner join dbo.adm_ValveGroup vgroup
                 on vgroup.ValveGroupID = vlog.ValveGroupID
              inner join dbo.valvegroup_log vlog
                 on station.StationID = vgroup.StationID
             where station.StationName in (''CBRN'')
               and vlog.logdate between ''2012-10-01'' and ''2012-10-30''
          ) x
          pivot
          (
             max(status)
             for ValveGroupName in (' + @cols + ')
          ) p '
```

However, since you are aggregating a string that will return a single row for each `ValveGroupName`, if you want to return multiple rows, then you'll need to include a `row_number`:

```
set @query = 'select ' + @cols + ' 
          from
          (
            select vlog.status,
                   vgroup.ValveGroupName,
                   seq = row_number() over(partition by vgroup.ValveGroupName               
                                             order by vlog.status)
              from dbo.adm_Station station,
              inner join dbo.adm_ValveGroup vgroup
                 on vgroup.ValveGroupID = vlog.ValveGroupID
              inner join dbo.valvegroup_log vlog
                 on station.StationID = vgroup.StationID
             where station.StationName in (''CBRN'')
               and vlog.logdate between ''2012-10-01'' and ''2012-10-30''
          ) x
          pivot
          (
             max(status)
             for ValveGroupName in (' + @cols + ')
          ) p '
```

This change will allow you to return multiple rows in each column.  Note: I also change the code to use `INNER JOIN` syntax instead of the comma joins, with the conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks. Why the inner joins rather than the comman joins if I'm not doing any left or right joins?

Comment: @KrisW The comma syntax was an INNER JOIN. I changed it to that syntax because that is the current standard for SQL.